# How do I make bootstrap table rows clickable?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I can hack this myself, but I think bootstrap has this capability.

Comment: They're already clickable. Did you want them to **do** something when clicked? If so, what?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Using jQuery it's quite trivial.  v2.0 uses the `table` class on all tables.

```
$('.table > tbody > tr').click(function() {
    // row was clicked
});
```

Comment: If you want to bind the click event only to the table body rows then use the '.table > tbody > tr' selector.

Comment: How to do this with specific table? Like i have 3 tables and i want to bind on click event on one table row then how am i get to do it

Comment: @MuneemHabib just add id to that table and use the id selector `$('#my_id > tbody > tr')`

Comment: Use `.on('click', function(){}); ` instead of `.click`

Comment: @MaHo Perhaps you can qualify why?

Comment: Readability and/or personal preference. Both will work as it is a shortcut for  `.on(click, handler).`  And to be honest, when i typed that comment, i thought .click was deprecated. But i got that mixed up with `.live() `.

Comment: @troelskn The reason why would be because with `.on`, if the table rows are pulled dynamically over AJAX or created in Javascript after the click handler loads, then you can still intercept it. It's akin to the deprecated but useful `.delegate` handler that's now part of the `.on` handler if specified properly.

Answer (score 57):

There is a [javascript plugin](http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/javascript#rowlink) that adds this feature to bootstrap.

When `rowlink.js` is included you can do:

```
<table data-link="row">
  <tr><td><a href="foo.html">Foo</a></td><td>This is Foo</td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="bar.html">Bar</a></td><td>Bar is good</td></tr>
</table>
```

The table will be converted so that the whole row can be clicked instead of only the first column.

Comment: nice work with your fork. Please adjust the example how to use twitter-bootstrap and your bootstrap version for this question.

Comment: Include both `bootstrap.css` and `jasny-bootstrap.css` and load `jasny-bootstrap.js`. For the use of rowlink see http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#rowlink

Comment: It seems that the accepted answer is simpler since most projects already use jQuery. Why double the upvotes here. No offense, just trying to understand why is this solution better?

Comment: @buffer The small plugin also handles triggering the click of the link and styling the row to make it clear it works as a link.
Sure, it's a trivial thing which a lot of developers could easily create themselves. The same could be said for Bootstrap's Collapse and Button plugins.

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels - your example on http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#rowlink only has first column clickable using Chrome ... doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels Your link seems to be broken, I get a 404 from Github.

Answer (score 25):

That code transforms any bootstrap table row that has `data-href` attribute set into a clickable element

Note: `data-href` attribute is a valid `tr` attribute (HTML5), `href` attributes on tr element are not.

```
$(function(){
    $('.table tr[data-href]').each(function(){
        $(this).css('cursor','pointer').hover(
            function(){ 
                $(this).addClass('active'); 
            },  
            function(){ 
                $(this).removeClass('active'); 
            }).click( function(){ 
                document.location = $(this).attr('data-href'); 
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: good answer. work like a charm!

Comment: brilliant solution, thanks

Answer (score 6):

I show you my example with modal windows...you create your modal and give it an id
then
In your table you have tr section, just ad the first line you see below (don't forget to set the  on the first row like this

```
<tr onclick="input" data-toggle="modal" href="#the name for my modal windows" >
 <td><label>Some value here</label></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfectly for me with the modals.

Answer (score 3):

```
<tr height="70" onclick="location.href='<%=site_adres2 & urun_adres%>'"
    style="cursor:pointer;">
```

Comment: -1 This approach is quite old and is not the best. Javastript should be unobtrusive, which means should not be mixed with html.

Comment: Yeah, but guess what? I don't have to load another bulky JS plugin or do attribute checking inside a jquery callback.

Comment: You can still do this without mixing js and html, using plain javascript

Answer (score 0):

May be you are trying to attach a function when table rows are clicked.

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].onclick = functioname(); //call the function like this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this way using bootstrap css. Just remove the active class if already assinged to any row and reassign to the current row.

```
    $(".table tr").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("class", "");
    });
    $(this).attr("class", "active");
```