# Clickable Table Cells, Not Rows

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible using Twitter Bootstrap to make part of a row, or a certain number of cells clickable, akin to this problem, but not for the whole row?

[How do I make bootstrap table rows clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002704/how-do-i-make-bootstrap-table-rows-clickable)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want each cell to be clickable? You could use code similar to that in the post you linked to:

```
$('.table td').click(function() {
    // cell was clicked
});
```

This will make every 'td' element clickable. If you want just some cells to be clickable, give them a special class and then reference that in the call. For instance, give your clickable cells a "clickable" class and use the following:

```
$('.table td.clickable').click(function() {
    // cell was clicked
});
```

Granted, this sets up a separate handler for each "td.clickable", rather than one event per row, but this can easily simulate making a portion of a row clickable.