# How to make bootstrap <tr> clickable with json table data source

Tags: php, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap at http://communitychessclub.com/games.php -it's a table that displays records of chess games. I want a row to be clickable like:

```
<?php 
echo "<tr onclick=\"location.href='basic.php?game=$game'\" >"; 
?>
```

The trouble is that the code to load and display the json table data doesn't include "TR" for displaying data; it's simply this:

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-url="games.json" data-cache="false" 
data-search="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" 
data-show-columns="true">

<thead>
<tr>

<th data-field="game" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md 
hidden-lg">#</th>
        <th data-field="Date">Date</th>
        <th data-field="ECO">ECO</th>
        <th data-field="Event">Event</th>
        <th data-field="WhiteElo">Rat.</th>
        <th data-field="White">White</th>
        <th data-field="BlackElo" >Rat.</th>
        <th data-field="Black">Black</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

</table>
```

I want to grab the game number (data-field="game") and

```
<?php 
echo "<tr onclick=\"location.href='basic.php?game=$game'\" >"; 
?>
```

How could I proceed?

Comment: I answer your question and I deleted it after checking out your source code in the link .. I am sorry

Comment: Can you not use ajax to call the json file, parse it and build a table with it.

Comment: It's parsed automatically... I could do it if had the syntax, but how to access data-field="game" and write a js inline script in <TR> to make the row genuinely clickable?

Comment: Parsing Automatically seems to be the problem

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002704/how-do-i-make-bootstrap-table-rows-clickable